# how to fix roll up error while building vue apps?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, web-deployment, rollupjs, npm-build

i want to deploy simple personal website using vue but when i try to npm run build this error come up help me please...
i try deleting the image but onother similiar error come's up

error during build:

```
RollupError: Could not resolve "../img/react%202.png" from "src/component/avatarmenu.vue"
    at error (file:///C:/Users/adity/OneDrive/Documents/LATIHAN/personal-w-vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:2041:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///C:/Users/adity/OneDrive/Documents/LATIHAN/personal-w-vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:23137 :24)
    at file:///C:/Users/adity/OneDrive/Documents/LATIHAN/personal-w-vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:23099:26
```

Comment: The path to the image is likely wrongful.

Answer (score 0):

Im so stupid,i just found out that you can't have a blank space in a image file name if you do that than vue would fill that blank with random stuff

Comment: FYI That the blank space was just encoded by something like `encodeURI('../img/react 2.png')`. This isn't random stuff.